# Receive-Job not outputting Until function is complete

Tags: powershell

I have the following function from a larger script:

```
function jobLogView {
    Write-Host "`n++++++++++++++++++++++++ Job Log +++++++++++++++++++++++++`n"
    Receive-Job -Name $script:jobSelect -AutoRemoveJob -Wait

    $jobLogNext = (Read-Host "View Another Completed Log? (y/n)").Trim()
    while ("y", "n" -icontains $jobLogNext -ieq '') {
        $jobLogNext = (Read-Host "Please use y or n").Trim()
    }

    if ($jobLogNext -ieq 'y') {
        jobList
    }
    elseif ($jobLogNext -ieq 'n') {
        Exit
    }
}
```

Once a job is selected the name is passed from a function to this one as `$script:jobSelect`.  As you can see from above this function outputs a header and then should display the output and remove the job.  However, currently it displays the header then jumps down to `$jobLogNext = (Read-Host "View Another Completed Log? (y/n)").Trim()`.  Once either `y/n` is selected the output of `Receive-Job` is displayed on the screen below `View Another Completed Log? (y/n)`.

I've tried setting the output of `Receive-Job` to a variable and then calling that variable below it, but I get the same results (I'd rather not output the results to a file).

Comment: Sounds like you need to get to know the `Wait-Job` cmdlet.

Comment: Doesn't that do the same thing as the `-Wait` flag of `Receive-Job`?  Also I should've mention that I have tried using `Wait-Job` program as well.

Comment: Also in my case only completed jobs will have `Receive-Job` run on them.

Comment: Add 

    | Out-Default 

after your receive job

Comment: Brilliant!  I've never heard of that cmdlet before.  thx @Doug Maurer